# Avoid object caching upon origin error with Cloudfront and Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm  using Cloudfront to serve json objects. In some rare cases, when Cloudfront reads the json from the origin, the response is being cut in the middle and Cloudfront caches a non valid json. I'm thinking to solve this case by writing a Lambda function that will validate the json when it is received from the origin. My question is how is it possible to tell Cloudfront-Lambda to avoid caching the object in case it's not valid?

Comment: Lambda@Edge can't access the payload.  You need to instead investigate how this is happening.  If you are not either sending a `Content-Length` response header from the origin or using chunked transfer encoding at the origin, CloudFront has no way of knowing that a response has been truncated and is incomplete.  If you are, then this condition should be impossible.

Comment: Content-Length header is being set correctly. However,  since the response size is pretty large and exceeds the buffer size, Tomcat automatically uses chunked transfer which removes the Content-Length header. I'm not sure how safe it is to increase the buffer size to the largest object served (say, 5M).

Comment: `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` *should be* just as good as `Content-Length`.  [Either of these signal CloudFront not to cache an object if it is incomplete.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#ResponseCustomDroppedTCPConnections) which is why I said above that this should be impossible -- CloudFront should simply not cache a partial object, as indicated by either of these mechanisms (chunked transfer encoding has an EOF marker `0\r\n\r\n` that signals no further content -- if not received, the response is incomplete).